# Caching meta data in JavaScript client

Tags: javascript

I am working with force.com architecture that uses a lot of JavaScript client side.  I need to cache some meta data across page requests.

As far as I'm aware it is impossible to cache JavaScript across page requests as the global name space will be reloaded.  One thing I was thinking that could be done if I was in a Java EE architecture which is ugly but would word be to generate a `MetaData.js` file with all the meta data at runtime.

This file could be cached across requests and the only cost would be instantiated an object from a self invoking function which is cheap.

However, I can create a `MetaData.js` file at runtime in force.com so I was wondering is there anything else I could do?

Comment: what browsers are you targetting? modern browsers can store data in local storage: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html . If you don't have too much data, using cookies in javascript might be an acceptable option as well.

Comment: @TimothéeGroleau I'll accept that as answer

Answer (score 0):

IS there a reason why you can't store that data on the server? With PHP in a `$_SESSION` for example.